# how to display data which contains number in div id in jstl

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, jstl

i want to show the specific form by id using jstl.in my view i have list of data.and for each list there is button for editting that data for that particular list.

```
 <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${!empty lists}">
    <c:forEach items="${lists}" var="list">
    <table class="data">
<input type="submit" value="edit list" id="${list.listNo }" onClick="openEdit(id)"  class="blue_button" style="width: 94%;" />
```

```
<form:form id="${list.listNo }" style="display:none;"
                                    method="post"
                                    action="//${list.listNo}"
                                    modelAttribute="list">

                                    <table id="list">
//it contains form data for list ,its generating form for each listno.this list no is integer like 234,777.
```

so what should i include in my javascript code so that it will show that particular form.?

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want?

```
<input type="submit" value="edit list" id="${list.listNo}" onClick="openEdit(${list.listNo})"  class="blue_button" style="width: 94%;" />
```

P.S. Consider to use `<c:out ...>` instead.